# compiling error in mpicc. attribute "__nonnull__" ignored extern int access (__const char *__name, int __type)

Tags: gcc, compiler-errors, mpi, mpich

My program is running at a super-computing center. This morning I asked the manager to install mvapich2-2.0rc1 (enable multiple thread). But after the installation, there are many errors while compiling. The errors are like:

```
/usr/include/unistd.h(256): error #1292: attribute "__nonnull__" ignored
  extern int access (__const char *__name, int __type) __THROW __nonnull ((1));
                                                               ^

/usr/include/unistd.h(432): error #1292: attribute "__nonnull__" ignored
       __THROW __nonnull ((1)) __wur;
               ^

/usr/include/unistd.h(442): error #1292: attribute "__nonnull__" ignored
       __THROW __nonnull ((1)) __wur;
               ^

/usr/include/unistd.h(455): error #1292: attribute "__nonnull__" ignored
  extern int chdir (__const char *__path) __THROW __nonnull ((1)) __wur;
                                                  ^

/usr/include/unistd.h(483): error #1292: attribute "__nonnull__" ignored
       __THROW __nonnull ((1)) __attribute_deprecated__ __wur;
......
```

My program is OK if I use openmpi compiler. But why there are so many errors using mvapich2-2.0rc1?

The makefile is:

```
exe_framework:*.* ../common/* ../data.h

/home/users/twang/mpi2/mvapich2-2.0rc1-icc.ifort-9.1-enable-mpi-threads/bin/mpicc *.c ../common/*.c -o exe_framework -g -lpthread -lm -rdynamic -Werror
```

How to solve the problem? Or, is it OK to ignore these problem by delete -Werror parameter?